# How to find the range and kernel of a linear transformation T(x1, x2, x3, x4...) = (x1, x3, x5, x7...)?

Tags: linear-transformations

It states in the question that the transformation drops every other term.

I've been looking online and a lot of the explanations involve stuff with matrices, and we haven't learned how to convert this sort of thing to a matrix yet (or maybe I'm just thinking about it wrong). Any help with this would be much appreciated.

I was thinking the range would just be R(T)={(x$_1$, x$_3$, x$_5$, x$_7$...)} but it seems weird that they would give it to us in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exactly wrong about the range; indeed the range of any $T : V \to W$ can always be written as $\{Tv: v \in V\}$. The issue is, they're searching for a very specific simplification. In general, there may not be much of a simplification, but in this case there is: the range is the entire space of sequences, i.e $T$ is surjective.

Think about it: given any sequence $(y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots)$, can you think of a sequence $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ so that
$$(y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots) = T(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (x_1, x_3, x_5, \ldots)?$$
Well, certainly $y_1 = x_1$ from the first term of each sequence, and $y_2 = x_3$, and $y_3 = x_5$, etc. So, so long as we set $x_{2n - 1}$ to be $y_n$, we should be OK, and indeed the other terms don't really matter. So, we could set
$$(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (y_1, 0, y_2, 0, y_3, 0, \ldots)$$
and it should work. The choice of using $0$s was arbitrary. We could set them, independently, to be anything we like. Another possibility would be
$$(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (y_1, y_1, y_2, y_2, y_3, y_3, \ldots).$$

As for the nullspace, think about what it means for
$$T(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (x_1, x_3, x_5, \ldots) = (0, 0, 0, \ldots).$$
We just need $x_1 = 0$ and $x_3 = 0$ and $x_5 = 0$, etc. The equation imposes no other restrictions. So, $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ will be in the kernel of $T$ if and only if $x_{2n - 1} = 0$ for all $n$.